# Custom drawing using System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, custom-controls

I want to mimick drawing of default border based on value of property `BorderStyle`.
Instead of single border around the control, my control is visualised as four adjacent custom-drawn boxes (2×2), each having standard border drawn individually. So for example, if `Control.Border` is set to `FixedSingle` value I want to draw single border around each box. Simplified example:

[image]

I have two related problems:

- using which standard method I can draw border from enumeration `System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle`?
- how do I determine pixel width of given border (e.g. `Fixed3D`) so I can use it in layout calculations?

Comment: As for the width: `SystemInformation.BorderSize.Width`and `SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Width`should do. But simply using `ControlPaint.DrawBorder` and `ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D` ought to be easier and more reliable..

Comment: If you think that `ControlPaint.DrawBorder` and `ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D` reliably use the same width as returned by `SystemInformation.BorderSize.Width` and `SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Width`, then please convert this into an answer. Thank you for pointing to places where the neccessary pieces are scattered.

Comment: Just don't, BorderStyle not a virtual property.  And rather imperfect, time has not been kind, the border of a TextBox, ComboBox and RichTextBox don't agree with each other.  Just add your own property, make it anything you want.

Comment: @HansPassant – after all, I implemented own property as you advised and left the original one as it is. Thank you for high-level view of how it goes with **BorderStyle** in Windows controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get results that reliably look like the `BorderStyles` on the machine you should make use of the methods of the `ControlPaint` object.

For testing let's do it ouside of a `Paint` event:

```
Panel somePanel = panel1;

using (Graphics G = somePanel.CreateGraphics())
{
    G.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, new Rectangle(11, 11, 22, 22));
    G.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, new Rectangle(44, 44, 66, 66));
    G.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, new Rectangle(11, 44, 22, 66));
    G.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, new Rectangle(44, 11, 66, 22));

    ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(G, new Rectangle(11, 11, 22, 22));
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(G, new Rectangle(44, 44, 66, 66));
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(G, new Rectangle(11, 44, 22, 66));
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(G, new Rectangle(44, 11, 66, 22));
}

Console.WriteLine("BorderSize.Width = " + SystemInformation.BorderSize.Width);
Console.WriteLine("Border3DSize.Width = " + SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Width);
```

On my machine this results in a screenshot similar to yours..:

[image]

..and these lines in the output:

> BorderSize.Width = 1
>
> Border3DSize.Width = 2

Comment: Thanks. I also give [Hans' comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30986553/custom-drawing-using-system-windows-forms-borderstyle#comment50005143_30986553) into attention. But first I'll stick with your answer and see how conistent results it produces over the time.

Comment: Well, Hans is usually right. Of course it depends on what you want to achieve. For results that go with the varying borderstyles on varying machines `ControlPaint` works fine. No need to be beter than the system..  Or you can combine the approaches using SystemColors to make sure the program won't clash with exotic user settings

Comment: The problem is that unlike the `DrawBorder3D()`, `DrawBorder()` has no default style and color. I would expect its overload with default system color and style, but instead I need to guess the values. Do you have any suggestion what the default values could be?

Comment: Doesn't it use the setting the user chose in his system settings? See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#colors)

Comment: It does *not* implicitly use anything because `DrawBorder()` has no version which performs drawing using implicit system settings.

Comment: I meant the __colors__ abd the __depth__. If the user has a brownish color scheme it should use the colors of this scheme when drawing its borders, no? There is no default style because you always can (and usually wiill) mix single, 3d or no border in one program.

Comment: You  __could__ read the colors used for a border effect by analyzing the pixels of a border, but that would not only defy the whole purpose of `ControlPaint` but be rather compliceted because you would not just have to read a few pixels but also infer the OS version style used to draw the border. Here 'style' means things like how __deep__ are the 3d effects and how much transparency is thrwon in. In Vista there was a lot in  Modern UI things are almost flat again.

Comment: OK, thank you for explanation on how did you mean that. So as I understand, I have just to draw border with any appropriate system color, no matter which one, and know it will fit in similar way in every color scheme.